# Method declaration in run time in java

Tags: java, methods, runtime, declaration

I try to declare a java method for a class in run time. I should not write the method in compile time or hard-code it. There is some way using reflection, I think but I cannot figure out how. How can this happen?

What all this came from:
I will read the input like;

```
name=john,age=21
name=smith,age=23
```

then I have to access all their "name"s and "age"s values with a method of "getname" and "getage".

However the name and age words can be changed to ie. surname and length; then I have to access their surname and length with the methods of "getsurname" and "getlength".

I know that I will use invoke to call getXXX methods. But how can I declare them during runtime?
That is the actual problem.

Comment: can you tell us why you want to do this?

Comment: @James.Xu I edited my question to tell why.

Comment: Why do you have to invoke `getXXX`? Why not store the values in a HashMap and call `getMyValue("name")`? Unless you gave an oversimplified version of your problem, this is shooting flies with cannons IMHO.

Comment: so the method set includes: {getname, getsurname, getlength, getage}, any more? is the method set infinite? It seems you are trying to use a gun to shoot a mosquito

Comment: @jornb87 Actually if that was my own project, I will to exactly same with what you told. However they want me to program it as I told.

Comment: @James.Xu yes, unfortunately it is infinite.

Comment: @AlockLeo .... why? Doing things really overly complex requires a really good reason. Invoking the compiler at runtime to do something as simple as this just doesn't sound right.

Comment: I'd like to also point out that, in addition to being very tricky in itself, creating method interfaces at runtime makes it more difficult to call these methods as well (because the calling code can obviously not be compiled against them). So you complicate both sides here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a byte code generation library like ASM, code snipplet library like BeanShell, or use the Compiler API to compile the class at runtime.

However, I also suspect you don't need to do this, and there is a much easier way.  Perhaps you can say what you want this method to do?

Answer (score 0):

[Reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) is not meant to add new methods to a class. There are some advanced tools Peter mentioned which may help you accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you might be able to use [proxy classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) and possibly a scripting language interpreter that is either written in or can interface with Java (e.g. [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/)). If you manage to integrate it with Rhino you'd probably have to write the method in Javascript but you can still access whatever Java objects you might need from it.